# Debugging problem

Tags: miktex, texmaker, debugging, ntheorem

I'm trying to find the bug in this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbding} % for checkmarks and XSolidBrush in itemize http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfauthor={fadf},pdftitle={faa},pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,pdfstartview={FitH},colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
{
\theoremprework{\vskip\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep\relax\par\ensuremath{\blacktriangleright}\small\vspace*{\dimexpr-\topsep-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
\theoremindent 2.5em
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{exercise}[prop]{Exercise}
}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}


\begin{document}
{

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\newtheorem{theorem}{Th\'eor\`eme}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{definition}{D\'efinition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercice}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Exemple}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}[chapter]
\newtheorem{solution}{S}


\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{Pr\'erequis}
\begin{flushright}
\small\emph{Mathematics possesses not only truth,\\but supreme beauty,\\such as only the greatest art can show.\\}\textsc{B. Russell}
\end{flushright}\normalsize


\chapter{Fonction r\'eelle d'une variable r\'eelle}
\begin{flushright}
\small\emph{Everyone knows what a curve is.\\until he has studied enough mathematics\\to become confused through the countless\\number of possible exceptions.\\}\textsc{Felix Klein}
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\section{Limites et asymptotes}
Un intervalle ouvert est un intervalle de la forme $]a;b[$ ou $]a;+\infty[$ ou $]-\infty;a[$ ou $\emptyset$ ou $\mathbb{R}=]-\infty;+\infty[$ avec $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
\\Un ensemble $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ est dit ouvert s'il est un intervalle ouvert ou une r\'eunion (finie ou infinie) d'intervalles ouverts.
\\Un ensemble $E$ est dit ferm\'e si son compl\'ementaire $\complement_{\mathbb{R}}^E$ est ouvert. Les intervalles ferm\'es sont de la forme $[a;b]$, $]-\infty;a]$, $[a;+\infty[$, $\emptyset$ ou $\mathbb{R}$.
\begin{exercise}
Pr\'eciser si chacun des ensembles suivants est ouvert ou ferm\'e:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $]-1;1[\cup]2;+\infty[$
\item $\{2\}$
\item $[1;4[$
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
Le centre de $]a;b[$ est $\displaystyle\frac{a+b}{2}$ et son rayon est $\displaystyle\frac{b-a}{2}$ ($a\leq b$). Ainsi l'intervalle ouvert de centre $x_0$ et de rayon $r$ est $]x_0-r;x_0+r[$. Un voisinage de $x_0$ est un intervalle ouvert de centre $x_0$ i.e. un intervalle de la forme $]x_0-r;x_0+r[$.
\begin{exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Donner un voisinage de $3$ de rayon $0.01$.
\item Soit $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ tel que $x_1<x_2$. Donner un voisinage $U$ de $x_1$ et un voisinage $V$ de $x_2$ tel que $U\cap V=\emptyset$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
Soit $E\subset\mathbb{R}$. Tout point de $E$ est soit un point d'accumulation de $E$, soit un point isol\'e. On dit que $x\to +\infty$ (respectivement $x\to -\infty$) si $\forall A\in\mathbb{R}$, $x>A$ (resp. $x<A$). $+\infty$ et $-\infty$ sont des symboles et pas des nombres r\'eels. Si $f:~D\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, on \'etudie les limites au points d'accumulations de $D$ (en pratique, on s'int\'eresse aux bornes ouvertes de $D$). Les formes ind\'etermn\'ees sont $+\infty-\infty$, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, $\frac{0}{0}$, $0\cdot\infty$, $0^0$ et $1^{\infty}$. Tout les autres formes sont d\'etermin\'ees.
\begin{proposition}
La limite d'une fonction est unique.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}
Si $f(x)<g(x)$ sur un voisinage de $x_0$ alors $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq \lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)$.
\end{proposition}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\XSolidBrush]Si $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=a$ alors $y=a$ est une AH \`a $(C_f)$.
\item[\XSolidBrush]Si $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\infty$ alors $x=a$ est une AV \`a $(C_f)$.
\item[\XSolidBrush]Si $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ alors on a une possibilit\'e d'avoir une AO $y=ax+b$ avec $\displaystyle a=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ et $\displaystyle b=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left[f(x)-ax\right]$.
\begin{itemize}
\item[\Checkmark] Si $a=0$ alors $(C_f)$ a une direction asymptotique horizontale.
\item[\Checkmark] Si $a=\infty$ alors $(C_f)$ a une direction asymptotique verticale.
\item[\Checkmark] Si $a\in\mathbb{R}^*$ et $b\in\mathbb{R}$ alors $(C_f)$ a une asymptote oblique $y=ax+b$.
\item[\Checkmark] Si $a\in\mathbb{R}^*$ et $b=\infty$ alors $(C_f)$ a une direction asymptotique parall\`ele \`a $y=ax$.
\end{itemize}
\item[\XSolidBrush]Si $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left[f(x)-(ax+b)\right]=0$ alors $y=ax+b$ AO \`a $(C_f)$\footnote{De m\^eme mani\`ere, $(C_g)$ est une courbe asymptote \`a $(C_f)$ si $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=0$.}.
\end{itemize}
\begin{exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
\item D\'emontrer que la droite d'\'equation $y=2$ est une AH \`a la courbe de $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x+1}$ en $+\infty$.
\item D\'emontrer que la droite d'\'equation $x=1$ est une AV \`a la courbe de $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}$.
\item D\'emontrer que la fonction $\displaystyle h(x)=\frac{3x-1}{2+x}$ admet deux asymptotes d'\'equations $x=-2$ et $y=3$.
\item D\'emontrer que la droite d'\'equation $y=2x-1$ est une asymptote \`a $\displaystyle j(x)=\frac{2x^2+x}{x+1}$ en $+\infty$ et en $-\infty$.
\item D\'eterminer l'AO \`a la courbe de $\displaystyle p(x)=\frac{2x^2+3x-5}{2x+1}$.
\item D\'eterminer les directions asymptotiques de $q(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $r(x)=1-x^2$ et $t(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}



}
\end{document}
```

The compiler says `Package ntheorem error: theorem style plain already defined`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Be sure you have closely read the manual http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf as there are many known conflicts and restrictions with a large number of other packages.

Comment: 1) remove `\usepackage{amsthm}` 2) use  `\begin{prop}...\end{prop}`

Comment: And  remove `\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter]` as you are redefining an existing item.   With this and the removal of `\usepackag{amsthm}`, recommended in the manual, your code compiles.

Comment: See section 3.2.2 in the documentation for `amsthm`: you must not have `\usepackage{amsthm}` along with `\usepackage{ntheorem}`.

Comment: @whatever I see an open brace after `\begin{document}` with the corresponding `}` before `\end{document}`. Remove them! They do evil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of modifications to: remove "Chapter 0", change the proposition identifiers, make the lengthy exercises look better

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

    % -- math packages
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}

    % -- fonts and related 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{color}

    % -- other packages     
    \usepackage{bbding} % for checkmarks and XSolidBrush in itemize 
                        % http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/in/symbols    /comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[pdftex,pdfauthor={fadf},pdftitle={faa},pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks,bookmarksopen,
    bookmarksnumbered,pdfstartview={FitH},colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red}]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cleveref} % declared after hyperref

    % -- declared operators
    \DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}


    % -- theorem declarations
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
    \theoremseparator{.}
    \theorembodyfont{\itshape}
    \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
    {
    \theoremprework{\vskip\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep\relax\par\ensuremath{\blacktriangleright}
    \small\vspace*{\dimexpr-\topsep-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
    \theoremindent 2.5em
    \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
    \newtheorem{exercise}[prop]{Exercise}
    }

    \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
    \theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
    \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
    \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
    %\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

    \newtheorem{theorem}{Th\'eor\`eme}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
    \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollaire}
    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
    \newtheorem{definition}{D\'efinition}[chapter]
    %\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercice}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{example}{Exemple}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{solution}{S}

    % -- end theorem declarations



    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter

    %\setcounter{chapter}{-1} 
    \chapter*{Pr\'erequis}
    \begin{flushright}
    \small\emph{Mathematics possesses not only truth,\\but supreme beauty,\\such as only the greatest art can show.\\}
    \textsc{B. Russell}
    \end{flushright}\normalsize


    \chapter{Fonction r\'eelle d'une variable r\'eelle}
    \begin{flushright}
    \small\emph{Everyone knows what a curve is.\\until he has studied enough mathematics\\to become confused through
    the countless\\number of possible exceptions.\\}\textsc{Felix Klein}
    \end{flushright}\normalsize
    \section{Limites et asymptotes}
    Un intervalle ouvert est un intervalle de la forme $]a;b[$ ou $]a;+\infty[$ ou $]-\infty;a[$ ou $\emptyset$ ou
    $\mathbb{R}=]-\infty;+\infty[$ avec $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
    \\Un ensemble $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ est dit ouvert s'il est un intervalle ouvert ou une r\'eunion (finie ou infinie)
    d'intervalles ouverts.
    \\Un ensemble $E$ est dit ferm\'e si son compl\'ementaire $\complement_{\mathbb{R}}^E$ est ouvert. Les intervalles
    ferm\'es sont de la forme $[a;b]$, $]-\infty;a]$, $[a;+\infty[$, $\emptyset$ ou $\mathbb{R}$.
    \begin{exercise}
    Pr\'eciser si chacun des ensembles suivants est ouvert ou ferm\'e:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $]-1;1[ \cup ]2;+\infty[$
    \item $\{2\}$
    \item $[1;4[$
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{exercise}
    Le centre de $]a;b[$ est $\displaystyle\frac{a+b}{2}$ et son rayon est $\displaystyle\frac{b-a}{2}$ ($a\leq b$).
    Ainsi l'intervalle ouvert de centre $x_0$ et de rayon $r$ est $]x_0-r;x_0+r[$. Un voisinage de $x_0$ est un
    intervalle ouvert de centre $x_0$ i.e. un intervalle de la forme $]x_0-r;x_0+r[$.
    \begin{exercise} \hfill 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Donner un voisinage de $3$ de rayon $0.01$.
    \item Soit $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ tel que $x_1<x_2$. Donner un voisinage $U$ de $x_1$ et un voisinage $V$ de $x_2$
    tel que $U\cap V=\emptyset$.
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{exercise}
    Soit $E\subset\mathbb{R}$. Tout point de $E$ est soit un point d'accumulation de $E$, soit un point isol\'e. On dit
    que $x\to +\infty$ (respectivement $x\to -\infty$) si $\forall A\in\mathbb{R}$, $x>A$ (resp. $x<A$). $+\infty$ et
    $-\infty$ sont des symboles et pas des nombres r\'eels. Si $f:~D\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, on \'etudie les limites
    au points d'accumulations de $D$ (en pratique, on s'int\'eresse aux bornes ouvertes de $D$). Les formes
    ind\'etermn\'ees sont $+\infty-\infty$, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, $\frac{0}{0}$, $0\cdot\infty$, $0^0$ et
    $1^{\infty}$. Tout les autres formes sont d\'etermin\'ees.
    \begin{prop}
    La limite d'une fonction est unique.
    \end{prop}

    \begin{prop}
    Si $f(x)<g(x)$ sur un voisinage de $x_0$ alors $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq \lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)$.
    \end{prop}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[\XSolidBrush]Si $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=a$ alors $y=a$ est une AH \`a $(C_f)$.
    \item[\XSolidBrush]Si $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\infty$ alors $x=a$ est une AV \`a $(C_f)$.
    \item[\XSolidBrush]Si $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ alors on a une possibilit\'e d'avoir une AO
    $y=ax+b$ avec $\displaystyle a=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ et 
    $\displaystyle b=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left[f(x)-ax\right]$.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[\Checkmark] Si $a=0$ alors $(C_f)$ a une direction asymptotique horizontale.
    \item[\Checkmark] Si $a=\infty$ alors $(C_f)$ a une direction asymptotique verticale.
    \item[\Checkmark] Si $a\in\mathbb{R}^*$ et $b\in\mathbb{R}$ alors $(C_f)$ a une asymptote oblique $y=ax+b$.
    \item[\Checkmark] Si $a\in\mathbb{R}^*$ et $b=\infty$ alors $(C_f)$ a une direction asymptotique parall\`ele \`a $y=ax$.
    \end{itemize}
    \item[\XSolidBrush]Si $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left[f(x)-(ax+b)\right]=0$ alors 
    $y=ax+b$ AO \`a $(C_f)$\footnote{De m\^eme mani\`ere, $(C_g)$ est une courbe asymptote \`a $(C_f)$ si
    $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=0$.}.
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{exercise} \hfill 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item D\'emontrer que la droite d'\'equation $y=2$ est une AH \`a la courbe de $\displaystyle 
    f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x+1}$ en $+\infty$.
    \item D\'emontrer que la droite d'\'equation $x=1$ est une AV \`a la courbe de $\displaystyle 
    g(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}$.
    \item D\'emontrer que la fonction $\displaystyle h(x)=\frac{3x-1}{2+x}$ admet deux asymptotes 
    d'\'equations $x=-2$ et $y=3$.
    \item D\'emontrer que la droite d'\'equation $y=2x-1$ est une asymptote \`a $\displaystyle 
    j(x)=\frac{2x^2+x}{x+1}$ en $+\infty$ et en $-\infty$.
    \item D\'eterminer l'AO \`a la courbe de $\displaystyle p(x)=\frac{2x^2+3x-5}{2x+1}$.
    \item D\'eterminer les directions asymptotiques de $q(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $r(x)=1-x^2$ et $t(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$.
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{exercise}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Also remove `times` that's overwritten by `fourier`. Also the order of the packages should be modified: `ntheorem` should definitely go before `hyperref` as well as `inputenc`, and `fontenc`. I usually have `fontenc`, `inputenc` and `babel` as the first group of packages. Finally, the `pdftex` option should not be specified for `hyperref`.

Comment: The theorem declaration should go ***before*** `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a debugged code. The main problem was you loaded both `amsthm` and `ntheorem`. I removed amsthm, because I know better ntheorem, it's easier to customise, and it can place automatically the end-of-proof symbol, even when the proof ends up in a displayed equation.

`hyperef` should beloaded *before* the first theorem declaration.

I took the liberty to replace `amsmath` by mathtools (a  very useful extension of amsmath) and to load `enumitem`, which I used to improve the enumerate and itemize environments displaying. I thought it was better ti use an unnumbered chapter for the prerequisites rather than a ‘number 0’ chapter, but you may change that easily. Finally, I replaced `\emptyset` by the better-looking `\varnothing`, and corrected a few typos. May I suggest that `i.e.` is an anglicism and should be replaced with `c.-à-d.`? Last comment: using `UTF8` encoding, you can type accented letters directly from the keyboard.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbding} % for checkmarks and XSolidBrush in itemize http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref, hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[pdftex, pdfauthor={fadf}, pdftitle={faa}, pdfpagemode={UseOutlines}, bookmarks, bookmarksopen, bookmarksnumbered, pdfstartview={FitH}, colorlinks, linkcolor={blue}, citecolor={blue}, urlcolor={red}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%% Theorems declarations
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Exemple}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}[chapter]

\theoremprework{\vskip\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep\relax\par\ensuremath{\blacktriangleright}\small\vspace*{\dimexpr-\topsep-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
\theoremindent 2.5em
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter]
\theoremprework{}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{solution}{S}
\theoremindent 0em
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}
{

  \tableofcontents
  \mainmatter


  %\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
  \chapter*{Prérequis}
  \begin{flushright}
    \small\emph{Mathematics possesses not only truth,\\but supreme beauty,\\such as only the greatest art can show.\\}\textsc{B. Russell}
    \end{flushright}


    \chapter{Fonction réelle d'une variable réelle}
    \begin{flushright}
      \small\emph{Everyone knows what a curve is.\\until he has studied enough mathematics\\to become confused through the countless\\number of possible exceptions.\\}\textsc{Felix Klein}
      \end{flushright}\normalsize

      \section{Limites et asymptotes}

      Un intervalle ouvert est un intervalle de la forme $]a;b[$ ou $]a;+∞[$ ou $]-∞;a[$ ou $\emptyset$ ou $\mathbb{R}=]{-∞};+∞[$ avec $a,b ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

      Un ensemble $E ⊂ \mathbb{R}$ est dit ouvert s'il est un intervalle ouvert ou une réunion (finie ou infinie) d'intervalles ouverts.

      Un ensemble $E$ est dit fermé si son complémentaire $∁_{\mathbb{R}}^E$ est ouvert. Les intervalles fermés sont de la forme $[a;b]$, $]-∞;a]$, $[a;+∞[$, $∅$ ou $\mathbb{R}$.
      \begin{exercise}
        Préciser si chacun des ensembles suivants est ouvert ou fermé:
        \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
          \item $]-1;1[ ∪ ]2;+∞[$
          \item $\{\mkern1.5mu 2 \mkern1.5mu\}$
          \item $[1;4[$
          \end{enumerate}
        \end{exercise}
        Le centre de $]a;b[$ est $\dfrac{a + b}{2} $ et son rayon est $\dfrac{b-a}{2}$ ($a\leq b$). Ainsi l'intervalle ouvert de centre $x₀$ et de rayon $r$ est $]x₀-r;x₀+r[$. Un voisinage de $x₀$ est un intervalle ouvert de centre $x₀$ i.e. un intervalle de la forme $]x₀-r;x₀+r[$.
        \begin{exercise}
          \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
            \item Donner un voisinage de $3$ de rayon $0{,}01$.
            \item Soit $x₁,x₂ ∈ \mathbb{R}$ tel que $x₁<x₂$. Donner un voisinage $U$ de $x₁$ et un voisinage $V$ de $x₂$ tel que $U ∩ V=∅$.
          \end{enumerate}
        \end{exercise}
        Soit $E ⊂ \mathbb{R}$. Tout point de $E$ est soit un point d'accumulation de $E$, soit un point isolé. On dit que $x\to +∞$ (respectivement $x\to -∞$) si $∀ A ∈ \mathbb{R}$, $x>A$ (resp. $x<A$). $+∞$ et $-∞$ sont des symboles et pas des nombres réels. Si $f:~D ―――→ \mathbb{R}$, on étudie les limites au points d'accumulations de $D$ (en pratique, on s'intéresse aux bornes ouvertes de $D$). Les formes indéterminées sont $+∞-∞$, $\frac{∞}{∞}$, $\frac{0}{0}$, $0 · \infty$, $0⁰$ et $1^{∞}$. Toutes les autres formes sont déterminées.
        \begin{proposition}
          La limite d'une fonction est unique.
        \end{proposition}

        \begin{proposition}
          Si $f(x)<g(x)$ sur un voisinage de $x₀$ alors $\lim\limits_{x\to x₀}f(x)\leq \lim\limits_{x\to x₀}g(x)$.
        \end{proposition}
        \begin{itemize}[label=\XSolidBrush]
          \item Si $\lim\limits_{x\to ∞}f(x)=a$ alors $y=a$ est une AH à $(C_f)$.
          \item Si $\lim\limits_{x\to x₀}f(x)=∞$ alors $x=a$ est une AV à $(C_f)$.
          \item Si $\lim\limits_{x\to ∞}f(x)=∞$ alors on a une possibilité d'avoir une AO $y=ax+b$ avec $\displaystyle a=\lim\limits_{x\to ∞}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ et $\displaystyle b=\lim\limits_{x\to ∞}\left[f(x)-ax\right]$.
                \begin{itemize}[label=\Checkmark, wide=0pt]
                  \item Si $a=0$ alors $(C_f)$ a une direction asymptotique horizontale.
                  \item Si $a=∞$ alors $(C_f)$ a une direction asymptotique verticale.
                  \item Si $a ∈ \mathbb{R}^*$ et $b ∈ \mathbb{R}$ alors $(C_f)$ a une asymptote oblique $y=ax+b$.
                  \item Si $a ∈ \mathbb{R}^*$ et $b=∞$ alors $(C_f)$ a une direction asymptotique parallèle à $y=ax$.
                \end{itemize}
          \item Si $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to ∞}\left[f(x)-(ax+b)\right]=0$ alors $y=ax+b$ AO à $(C_f)$\footnote{De m\^eme manière, $(C_g)$ est une courbe asymptote à $(C_f)$ si $\lim\limits_{x\to ∞}[f(x)-g(x)]=0$.}.
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{exercise}
          \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
            \item Démontrer que la droite d'équation $y=2$ est une AH à la courbe de $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x+1}$ en $+∞$.
            \item Démontrer que la droite d'équation $x=1$ est une AV à la courbe de $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{x²+1}{x²-1}$.
            \item Démontrer que la fonction $\displaystyle h(x)=\frac{3x-1}{2+x}$ admet deux asymptotes d'équations $x=-2$ et $y=3$.
            \item Démontrer que la droite d'équation $y=2x-1$ est une asymptote à $\displaystyle j(x)=\frac{2x²+x}{x+1}$ en $+∞$ et en $-∞$.
            \item Déterminer l'AO à la courbe de $\displaystyle p(x)=\frac{2x²+3x-5}{2x+1}$.
            \item Déterminer les directions asymptotiques de $q(x)=√{x}$, $r(x)=1-x²$ et $t(x)=x+√{x}$.
          \end{enumerate}
        \end{exercise}
      }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the corresponding code, for completeness.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas:  It seems I forgot to post the code, and you're the first to point it! Fortunately, it was not deleted from my computer, so I could fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have planted several bugs in your document. The most important one is that you shouldn't load both `amsthm` and `ntheorem` (see section 3.2.2 in the manual of `ntheorem`). Since you're using the syntax of the latter, remove `\usepackage{amsthm}`

You have other minor or less minor bugs, though.

1. `\usepackage{times}` is overridden by `\usepackage{fourier}`
2. `ntheorem` should be loaded before `hyperref`
3. The same is true for most packages (except `cleveref`, in this document). I usually recommend `fontenc`, `inputenc` and `babel` as the first group of packages.
4. The `pdftex` option should not be specified for `hyperref`.
5. The open brace `{` after `\begin{document}` and the matching `}` before `\end{document}` are wrong and must be removed (you risk memory overflow with them).
6. Theorems should be declared before `\begin{document}`.

Here's an edited version.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{bbding} % for checkmarks and XSolidBrush in itemize http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[
  pdfauthor={fadf},
  pdftitle={faa},
  pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
  bookmarks,
  bookmarksopen,
  bookmarksnumbered,
  pdfstartview={FitH},
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={blue},
  citecolor={blue},
  urlcolor={red}
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]{%

{
  \theoremprework{%
    \vskip\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep\relax\par
    \ensuremath{\blacktriangleright}%
    \small\vspace*{\dimexpr-\topsep-\baselineskip}\leavevmode
  }%
  \setlength{\theoremindent}{2.5em}
  \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
  \newtheorem{exercise}[prop]{Exercise}
}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}

\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Th\'eor\`eme}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{definition}{D\'efinition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercice}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Exemple}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}[chapter]
\newtheorem{solution}{S}


\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

[...]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you didn't remove `\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercice}[chapter]` and theorem, proposition, corollary... are proof like style